# How can I call test function in the body of main?

Tags: rust

I have the following program where I want to call the `open_door` function in the test module from the main function.
How can I do that?

I know that `cfg(test)` conditionally compiles that piece of code when using `cargo test` but how can I tell it to compile it everytime?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Door {
    is_open: bool,
}

impl Door {
    fn new(is_open: bool) -> Door {
        Door { is_open }
    }
}

trait Openable {
    fn open(&mut self);
}

impl Openable for Door {
    fn open(&mut self) {
        self.is_open = true
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    pub fn open_door() {
        let mut door = Door::new(false);
        println!("1: {:?}", door);
        door.open();
        println!("2: {:?}", door);
        assert!(door.is_open);
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    use tests;
    tests::open_door();
}
```

I get the following error when trying to run the above code:

```
  Compiling chp1 v0.1.0 (/home/ab/personal/Hands-On-Data-Structures-and-Algorithms-with-Rust/practice/chp1)
error[E0432]: unresolved import `tests`
  --> practice/chp1/src/main.rs:37:9
   |
37 |     use tests;
   |         ^^^^^ no external crate `tests`
   |
help: consider importing this module instead
   |
37 |     use core::num::bignum::tests;
   |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `chp1` due to previous error
```

Comment: Don't think of this as Python where you run the script to run tests, use `cargo test`. Code within `#[cfg(test)]` **does not exist** unless you are explicitly compiling in `test` mode. This is to ensure that test code doesn't slow down or end up in your release builds.

Comment: Why does `main()` needs to reference tests code? This sounds problematic.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a good justification for doing this, rust provides a well documented guidelines for testing, and making your tests always compile will only slow down your project when you build it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I adopted the below approach:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Door {
    is_open: bool,
}

impl Door {
    fn new(is_open: bool) -> Door {
        Door { is_open }
    }
}

trait Openable {
    fn open(&mut self);
}

impl Openable for Door {
    fn open(&mut self) {
        self.is_open = true
    }
}

mod tests {
    use super::*;
    pub fn open_door() {
        let mut door = Door::new(false);
        println!("1: {:?}", door);
        door.open();
        println!("2: {:?}", door);
        assert!(door.is_open);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_open_door(){
        open_door();
    }

}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    use tests;
    tests::open_door();
}
```

Update (after reading the comments below):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Door {
    is_open: bool,
}

impl Door {
    fn new(is_open: bool) -> Door {
        Door { is_open }
    }
}

trait Openable {
    fn open(&mut self);
}

impl Openable for Door {
    fn open(&mut self) {
        self.is_open = true
    }
}

pub fn open_door() {
    let mut door = Door::new(false);
    println!("1: {:?}", door);
    door.open();
    println!("2: {:?}", door);
    assert!(door.is_open);
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::open_door;
    #[test]
    fn test_open_door() {
        open_door();
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    open_door();
}
```

Comment: The idiomatic organization would be to move `open_door` outside the module and put `#[cfg(test)]` back on `mod tests`. Functions should not be in a "tests" module unless they're exclusive to testing. And without `#[cfg(test)]` there is an additional cost to compile the test function even when not used like building normally (its not going to matter much here, but that's the motivation for it).

Comment: This only makes things worse. Use `cargo test`. **Don't do this.** There is a well-defined way for doing this in Rust you really should use, as it makes your project comprehensible to other Rust developers.

Comment: I moved the open_door func outside the test module and have put the test feature flag back on the test module.

Answer (score 1):

Run with `cargo test` or remove `#[cfg(test)]` and `#[test]`.

Comment: Is it possible to add some other feature to make it available to main func?

Comment: @Ayush Bindlish Yes you can add more functions in the module, it will work. Just don't add the `#[test]` attribute if it is not for testing. Btw, you don't need the `use tests;` in the main function.